# CodenameOne: Captured images cannot be accessed

Tags: java, codenameone

I want to send multiple photos to an API.

I'm using Capture.capturePhoto() and then saving the string to an array.

I want to add the files as part of a Multipart call, but, lopping through the array and testing if the files exists fails:

```
Boolean exists = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().exists(filename);  // exists is always false.
// File shows as file://C:/Users/Tony/AppData/Local/Temp/temp1168027126450232196.jpg 
// The file DOES, however, exist in the OS

// This call fails because filename "does not exist", according to the FileSystemStorage class
request.addData(fn, filename, "image/jpeg");
```

Is this a simulator issue? or should I access the file differently?

Comment: This should work. This is the [code to exists](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/JavaSE/src/com/codename1/impl/javase/JavaSEPort.java#L10486) in the simulator. You can open that file and place a breakpoint there to see that the `unfile` method returns the correct file name. Can you create a test case I can run to see the failure?

Comment: I got it to work.  and my upload to my API call works nicely now.

unfile, btw as in JavaSEPort and had protected access.  It worked, however, without using the unfile method.  .addData accepted the file from capture() method.

Comment: I don't follow, what did you change?

Comment: I was trying to Unfile() the string returned from the capture().  I didn't need to manipulate it at all - addData() accepted the "file://" version of the filename.

Comment: Yes. unfile is an internal concept of the simulator. It's there to create an environment that's more like the devices.